# Strunk and White - No review stats?

Tags: support, badges, edit-badges

On the main SO site, I have received the `Strunk and White` badge and I read that you start seeing your editing/reviewing stats.  Where exactly is this?  I don't seem to be able to find it, or I do not have this data available to me.

Any ideas?

Comment: Click the Review link in the title bar at the top next to your badge counts.  Click on one of the tabs (`first answers`,`first questions`, etc.) and it will be on the right side of the page.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> The review stats are [here](https://stackoverflow.com/review/). Once inside, you can see the reviews you've made and the progress towards the next badge, which is the Copy Editor badge. Here's how it looks in mine:

[image]

> Once you've reached 10k, it also shows you the questions that have pending close votes and you can sort them by # of close votes or close reason.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You have [no meta revisions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/172155/shark?tab=activity&sort=revisions) and [many SO revisions](https://stackoverflow.com/users/596075/shark?tab=activity#page_1-filter_revisions).