# Change verbiage on 'review' tab sidebar regarding review tracking and Strunk & White badge

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, review

See these related meta questions:

[Strunk and White - No review stats?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/113029/strunk-and-white-no-review-stats)

[Strunk & White and Review Stats](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/111699/strunk-white-and-review-stats)

I suggest changing the verbiage on the 'review' Strunk & White progress sidebar to clearly state that review tracking will start once the Strunk & White badge has been earned, and not beforehand.  Several users (including me) were left with the impression that the review stats were already being tracked, and would simply be made visible upon earning the badge.  Instead, we were greeted with an empty review history after earning the Strunk & White badge.  Changing the expectations of the user via clearer verbiage in the review tab will help avoid the disappointment of seeing the empty review tab.

Comment: Or track the stats and let us progress towards Reviewer, just don't show us. Disappointing when you think you're halfway there but end up with 0 and already voted/edited half the posts on the site

Comment: Yes Please!! I agree with both of you. I just got `S&W` on SF and see my review stats as all zeros! :'(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We now have new badges and a new way to see your badge progress so we're calling this one good.  Hover over the reviewer bar at the top to see your stats and progress towards the review badges.  [image]